# Android - FirebaseMessaging - FirebaseInstanceId﹕ background sync failed: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying **Firebase Cloud messaging** , i am follow instruction in this example [here](https://www.codementor.io/android/tutorial/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase) but i found this message in log cat window in my android studio:
com.example.tareq.news D/FirebaseInstanceId﹕ background sync failed: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE, retry in 320s

please any one can help me? thanks.

***EDIT:***
I have now a new exeption that is:

```
D/FirebaseApp﹕ com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
```

D/FirebaseApp﹕ Initialized class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.
D/FirebaseApp﹕ com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization
D/FirebaseApp﹕ Initialized class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.
I/FirebaseInitProvider﹕ FirebaseApp initialization successful

***EDIT again:***

I found the problem, it is i have android studio version 1.0 but in the requirement mentioned that require android studio version 1.5 or higher
[this image from firebase documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWWOF.png)

Comment: are you using device or emulator?

Comment: yes i using  Genymotion emulator

Comment: is it solved???you need to install google play service

Answer (score 7):

Please check if you have Google Play Services installed in your device. Firebase won't work or run without it.

I'd suggest you to use the official [Firebase documentation for sending Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience) as reference.

If you encounter an issue, you might want to check or compare your implementation with the [Firebase Cloud Messaging Quickstart project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/).

Comment: I run my application on Genymotion emulator, Should i install google play services on ti?

Comment: @TareqBallan - looks like you've already solved the first issue. I also updated my answer, so please check it out.